# Why is the app keeps waiting for Debugger?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

In Android API 24, custom phone 7.0.0

When I launch application in **normal mode** it works perfectly  but whenever I switch to **debug mode** it shows this messages in logcat and `keep showing Waiting for Debugger Dialog`.

> W/ActivityThread: Application com.xxx.xxxxx is waiting for the
>   debugger on port 8100...  I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

[image]

What I've tried so far:

1. **[Android Studio "waiting for debugger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586136/android-studio-waiting-for-debugger)**

Issue : Doing Kill again and again is tedious task as this happens every time with debug mode

2. **[Why is the app waiting for the debugger when its not connected to computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031070/why-is-the-app-waiting-for-the-debugger-when-its-not-connected-to-computer)**

Issue : This works temporary again doing debug(second or third time) will give same dialog again

3. **[Debugging with Android Studio stuck at "Waiting For Debugger" forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436050/debugging-with-android-studio-stuck-at-waiting-for-debugger-forever)**

I can't believe a device reboot is the only solution.

**The Question?**

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the app stucked on this screen ? It normally disappears after a few seconds

Comment: @ArthurAttout, It doesn't until and unless I restart the device.

Comment: Did you try [adding SET_DEBUG_APP in permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375505/7540393) ?

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 8):

You might have added your app in **Select app to be debugged** on your phone. In **Settings** -> **Developer Options** -> **Select app to be debugged**

To resolve this, go to **Select app to be debugged** and click on **No apps**

Answer (score 0):

I think you enable Select debug app  in Developer Options. Try go Setting - > Developer Options -> TurnOf Debug.